# Setup web server copying response from another server with nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver

I would like to configure a nginx server which will be continously connected to another web server - with mjpeg stream. My new web server should copy the response it gets and send it to any client connected to it (to the new server). I cannot just connect clients to the original web server providing mjpg stream as it gets blocked on first connection, I am trying to bypass it somehow. I tried reverse proxy, but its still blocking the original server after first connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this purely with Nginx.  You need something that can take the stream, buffer, and output streams that start in the right place.

There are a couple ways to handle this.  One is to create a custom server with Node.js or something that does what you need.  Another is to transcode this MJPEG stream to something else, such as an HLS stream.  This will be more efficient, can be served with Nginx, but will increase latency a bit.